# problem by incrementing a value What can it be?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with the variable increment, it never increments and always gets the value 1, which I'm doing wrong?

```
function start(N) {
    var acrescentar = 0;
    var sequencia = ['hello', 'word', 'today'];
}
```

Comment: how are you calling `start`?? and why are you declaring `increment` twice?

Comment: What is the purpose of this program? Is it a codility question pasted here without context?

Comment: Maybe, because you are resetting the variable to `0` before incrementing it every time... Please, clean the code first, there are multiple declarations of the same variable too.

Comment: I correct and I still have a problem

Comment: So what is the value of 'N'? also remove that second var increment = 0 in the loop.

Comment: I need to zero the variable in each loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your logic.  The only time `increment` will have 1 added to it is when the `if` condition is met.  The very first thing that you do after meeting that `if` condition is `increment = 0;`

For this reason, you will *never* see a value greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

on line 7 you always reset increment to 0. You should remove that line

Comment: Don't do the assignment to 0 inside the for cycle if you want that variable to increment. Put the declaration and the initialization to 0 just before the for loop.

Comment: I need to zero the variable in each loop

Comment: You think you need based on your interpretation of the problem. But maybe you don't since what your program does doesn't lead anywhere. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I need to zero the variable in each loop

Comment: Ok so you wrote a program to test if the instatialization of a variable works. In that case your program works. Just a guess since you don't really give much to work on: maybe you want to loop over the sequence of words and have a nested loop and only in that loop reset the variable to 0?

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help you. Good luck